# postgres SQL function with variables

Tags: postgresql

Can anyone tell me why does not insert this function anything into the table?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_one(_temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    TEMP INT := NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT "temptable"."id" INTO TEMP FROM "temptable" WHERE "tmpstr" = _temp;
    IF TEMP IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO "temptable"("tmpstr") values(_temp);
        SELECT CURRVAL("id") FROM "temptable" INTO TEMP;
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably get an error because there is no sequence called `id`.

You are probably looking for

```
INSERT INTO temptable (tmpstr)
   VALUES (_temp)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
RETURNING id;
```